# Check realm create function returning object new or updated

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

When we create realm object with primary key:

```
class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var someValue: Int = 0
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? { return "id" } 
}

let realm = try! Realm()
realm.write {
    let dog = realm.create(Dog.self, value:["id" : 1], update: .modified)
    if dog.isNew { //need to check dog is newly created or an existing object. 
        dog.someValue = 0
    } else {
        dog.someValue += 1
    }
}
```

how we can check the dog object above is newly created or updated?

Comment: The question is a bit vague; If you want to update an object then you would know it's id before trying to update it. Also, I don't believe the `let dog = realm` is valid syntax - it will probably throw an exception. If you pass true (which is depreciated) it will work. Can you explain the use case a bit further?

Comment: @Jay its a valid syntax. `let dog = realm.create(Dog.self, value:["id" : 1], update: .modified)` will create a new dog object if it doesn't exist or otherwise will update the object if it exist. The use case here is if it already exist i have to increment one of its variable otherwise just set it to 0. I will update the question to be more clear.

Comment: I am familiar with the function. Updated to Realm 3.17 and it's working correctly, just need to change `realm.write` to `try! realm.write`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the create function has a direct way to indicate if the object was created or modified. It's a great feature request though; It would be handy to know if an object was created or existing in the realm.create call.

That being said, this is a solution to the question that will check and indicate if an object is created or modified.

The first time the code is run, it will create an object with a primary key of 0 and print it to console. Running it again will increment the someValue property of that object and print the updated objects someValue.

The code checks if the object with a given primary key exists; if no then create a new object with the default value for someValue. If yes, then increment someValue and update the object.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let primaryKey = 0
guard let dog = realm.object(ofType: Dog.self, forPrimaryKey: primaryKey) else {
    try! realm.write {
        let newDog = realm.create(dog.self, value:["id" : primaryKey, "someValue" : 0], update: .modified)
        print("new dog created: \(newDog)")
    }
    return
}

try! realm.write {
    dog.someValue += 1
    realm.add(dog, update: .modified)
    print("existing object updated \(dog)")
}
```